# Scripting REST API with Load Runner

Tags: api, rest, jmeter, load-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to script a **REST API in JSON** format with Load Runner tool but getting the error as

> Action.c(11): Error -27493: Client authentication certificate needed but is not available. Use "web_set_certificate" or "web_set_certificate_ex" to specify a certificate.    [MsgId: MERR-27493]

However, the same setup is working fine for me in JMeter without adding any specific certificates. I have made sure that, I have same headers added in both JMeter (5.5) and LoadRunner (ver 2022).

I have made sure to add web_set_user for basic authentication for the Rest API

Looking for inputs on how can this error be resolved so that, i can get the response of HTTP 200 from Load Runner

Answer (score 2):

Most probably in JMeter you have the relevant configuration performed via system.properties file like it's described in the [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/client-side-performance-testing-using-jmeter)

If this is the case - inspect the system.properties file, figure out the [keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) path and the password, get the certificate from the keystore, convert it into PEM format using i.e [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) tool and feed the certificate to LoadRunner using  [web_set_certificate_ex()](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2022-2022-r2/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_set_certificate_ex.htm) function